# How to compare strings with user input?

Tags: c, c-strings, gcc-warning

I have a question in my paper. I have 10 employee ids M001,A004,D007,etc...User is inputting one of the the mentioned Ids and if the id is not there it prints id not found. I tired with strcmp and got stuck. Its good if you tell me a way to do it? Thanks, note: i am a beginner in C.I am trying an easy way now it gives the error with the for loop.

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    float tSalary(float salary,float bonus);
    char searchid(char search);
    int main(void)
    {
       char status,input,search,C,P;
       char searchId[8][4]={"M001","A004","D007","D010","D012","Q008","Q015","DE09"};
       float salary,bonus,tSalary;
       int i,j;

       do{
          printf("Enter the employee id: ");
          scanf("%s", &search);
          printf("Enter the job status: ");
          scanf("%s", &status);  
          printf("Enter the salary: ");
          scanf("%f", &salary);

          for(i=0;i<8;i++){              //This is where all things go wrong
             for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                if(searchid[i][j]=search){    //the [i] where the subscripted error occurs 
                   printf("Id is valid\n");
                }
                else printf("Invalid id\n");

             }
          }

        printf("Do you want to enter another record?(Y-Yes/N-No): ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        }while(input=='Y'||input=='y');
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You want strings instead of `char`s

Comment: @KeineLust Please tell me a way to do it

Comment: I found one problem in your code `  if(searchid[i][j]=search){    //the [i] where the subscripted error occurs 
                   printf("Id is valid\n");
                }`
                 here its `==` not assignment that is `=`?

Comment: Many problems here. The multiple prints of "Id id valid\n" are because code prints this after checking every character in `searchId`. As noted by @LethalProgrammer, the `=` assignment operator is used instead of the `==` comparison operator. But, even before this there is big trouble, since `search` and `status` are `char`s, but are treated as strings by input code. If `search` is a string, `==` can  not be used, but `strcmp()` should instead be used.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input/format specifier, always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is on less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow.  Such overflow results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few problems in the posted code. For starters, `searchId` should be declared as `searchId[8][5]`, to make room for the `\0` terminator at the end of each string.

It appears from the input code that `status` and `search` should hold strings, but these are declared as `char`s. After fixing this, note that there is no need for the address operator `&` in the calls to `scanf()` that read into these arrays. Also, maximum widths should always be specified when using the `%s` conversion specifier with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.

Strings can not be compared using the `==` comparison operator, so `strcmp()` should be used here. This can be done in a loop that steps through the array of strings; the loop exits when the index reaches 8, or a comparison is successful. Then, after the loop, if the index has reached 8 (all valid id strings failed the test) the `search` string was not valid.

Here is a modified version of the posted code that implements all of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float tSalary(float salary,float bonus);
char searchid(char search);

int main(void)
{
    char status[1000];
    char search[1000];
    char input, C, P;
    char searchId[8][5] = { "M001", "A004", "D007", "D010",
                            "D012", "Q008", "Q015", "DE09" };
    float salary, bonus, tSalary;
    int i, j;

    do {
        printf("Enter the employee id: ");
        scanf("%999s", search);
        printf("Enter the job status: ");
        scanf("%999s", status);  
        printf("Enter the salary: ");
        scanf("%f", &salary);

        i = 0;
        while (i < 8 && strcmp(search, searchId[i]) != 0) {
            ++i;
        }

        if (i < 8) {
            printf("Id is valid\n");
        } else {
            printf("Invalid id\n");
        }

        printf("Do you want to enter another record?(Y-Yes/N-No): ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
    } while (input == 'Y' || input == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Sample program interaction:

```
Enter the employee id: A004
Enter the job status: pending
Enter the salary: 2000
Id is valid
Do you want to enter another record?(Y-Yes/N-No): y
Enter the employee id: Q015
Enter the job status: completed
Enter the salary: 3000
Id is valid
Do you want to enter another record?(Y-Yes/N-No): y
Enter the employee id: B001
Enter the job status: completed
Enter the salary: 1200
Invalid id
Do you want to enter another record?(Y-Yes/N-No): n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort and help.I learnt a lot from you.Is this also an alternative `searchId[8][4]={ "M001", ....."Q008", "Q015", "DE09", "\0" };` ? I didn;t know about the buffer overflow in strings, Now i know what is the importance. `strcmp` was the trouble part and the calling the values in the array.Thank you so much for the brief explanation and solving the problem.I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JinaPerera-- You are welcome. Your alternative proposal will not work; consider that `"M001"` is a string which contains 4 `char`s plus a null-terminator. That might look like `char arr[5] = "M001"`, which is the same thing as `char arr[5] = { 'M', '0', '0', '1', '\0' }`. For this reason you need `searchId[8][5]`, to declare an array of 8 arrays of 5 `char`s. Your alternative adds a 9th string to the mix, so would need to be `searchId[9][5]`, still needing `[5]` for all of the characters in the original strings.

Comment: Note that you do sometimes see lists of strings like this with the final string empty, but this is usually expressed as something like: `char strings[4][5] = { "str1", "str2", "str3", "" }`. The final empty string serves to mark the end of the list of strings.

Comment: Thats a wonderful explanation @David Bowling .Understood very well.I would have to do some exercises and practice this.Its good to know about the null terminator(the placement and declaring the arrays). A place where i can possibly go wrong.Thank you once again.